# APC 500 Internal server error

Tags: php, 500-internal-error

I have a blog running on a FreeBSD 8.1 system with PHP 5.3.5 and APC 3.1.6.

At first everything seemes fine, but after a while (about 18-24 hours) all pages are served blank, and with a status code of 500. There is nothing in either the vhost, or the global Apache error logs, and PHP doesn't log anything either. The requests are only logged in the access log, with a 500 code. All the other vhosts on the server run fine while the blog is down. An Apache restart fixes the problem.

PHP error logging is enabled (the deprecated functions are logged) while the site is working.

Disabling APC for this vhost solved the issue, but that is not a long term solution, because the CPU load is roughly doubled this way.

Is this a WP issue, or an APC bug?

**EDIT**
Forgot to add WP version, it is version 3.1.3

Comment: Do you have access to apc.php? Can you browse to that and look at the stats shown?

Comment: Yes, I have, but for that I have to re-enable APC, wait for it to "crash" again, and not restart apache until I dump all of the data. This is problematic for a site with that much traffic.

Comment: do you have munin or any other system monitoring agent installed? and why do you need to re-enable APC to use apc.php?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Yes, I have Munin on the server and added the php-apc module just now. Right now the issue seemes to be that APC ran out of memory, so I'm trying it now with an increased shm_size.

Comment: What are you apc.ini settings?  Are you using any user caching (W3 Total Cache, Super Cache etc.)?  Sounds like your cache is getting full and your server doesn't have enough memory to handle it.

Comment: And I need to re-enable it on the WP vhost to have it's data included in apc.php, APC runs fine with the other sites (they have lower traffic though).

Comment: Chris, APC settings were at the default values, and I'm using Super Cache. You are right, probably when the cache files expired they were still cached by APC, and occupied memory. I'll check it till tomorrow with the raised shm_size, then try adjusting the ttl values.

Comment: It seems I have same issue with Wordpress 3.3.1, APC 3.1.9 with default configuration and wp-super-cache. Could you fix it ?

Comment: On the surface this doesn't appear to be a WP issue, and no one has provided any details otherwise.  Closing as off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Raising [apc.shm_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.shm-size) from default value 32M to 256M in php.ini seems to do the trick for us.

**edit**: raising that value is not a bad idea, however it does not solve the issue in the long term. We are now considering removing either APC or Super Cache...

Answer (score 0):

- 500 ISE may indicate a problem with the configuration on the server. It could be a problem with your .htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but since the whole site works fine for a while, then all pages return a 500 error, and there are no error messages in the logs, and disabling APC solves the problem, this is not a .htaccess problem.